# 'transition_post_status' only fires when pressing "Add New"

Tags: posts, post-status

I want to fire a function when a new post (cpt) is published.

```
function my_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && 'publish' !== $old_status ) {
          // do s.th.
    }
    debug_to_console( $post );
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_publish', 10, 3 );
```

So when I hit the "Add New" button, the function is fired and I get my console log with the `$post` content. And that's it.

The function than never fires again. Neither when I publish the post nor when a post is updated or the status of a post is changed.

I also tried the common other hooks like:

```
add_action('future_to_publish', 'my_publish');
add_action('new_to_publish', 'my_publish');
add_action('draft_to_publish' ,'my_publish');
add_action('auto-draft_to_publish' ,'my_publish');
```

those never did anything.

I did a lot of research the last days and tried a lot of different solutions but nothing helped to get me over this... any Ideas?

Comment: My recommendation would be to test with the core `post` or `page` post types, in order to narrow down the source of your problem. If your custom post type does not use `wp_insert_post()` to create or modify posts the hooks will not be fired.

Comment: @NateWr I tried also on normal posts and pages. Just forgott to mention it in the question. `my_publish` only fires, when the `"Add New"` button is clicked, doesn't matter which post-type.

Comment: Something sounds off about your setup, because by default clicking "Add New" on the post page does not create a post. The auto-draft isn't created until you've typed something into the title or post editor.

Comment: @NateWr I just checked on a completely new and plain WP-installation. And the same result as above. The function gets fired as soon as I het the "add new" button. And when I update a post, it doesn't do anything...

Comment: OK, I got the bug! The function `debug_to_console( $post );` caused the problem. This was echoing a `<script>` tag....

Answer (score -1):

This will do something when you publish a post in the backend.

```
function my_publish( $post_id ) {
   if ( ( $_POST['post_status'] === 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {
     error_log('WordPress would be better if it did not use Google Fonts.  Looking forward to the system fonts.');
   }
}
add_action( 'publish_yourCustomPostType', 'my_publish', 10, 3 );
```